# How can I display an image (dynamically retrieving from a JSON service) in the TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, uitableview

I get the url image from a JSON service. I know how to display it on a screen using an `UIImageView` object but I don't know how I can do it in a `UITableViewCell` cause I cannot drag and drop the `UIImageView` object onto a prototype cell. I checked some of the resources but they are all very confusing and the difference between displaying an image on the screen and on the `UITableViewCell` is not clear. I am sure replies of this post will help solving this confusion for a lot of developers like me!

My question is, what is the difference between displaying an image on the screen and on the `UITableViewCell` in code level? (Do we use `UIImageView` object in `UITableViewCell` as well? Do we drag and drop anything? Do we need `contentView` or `subview`? etc.)

Comment: if you are using default UITableViewCell, it have a property called imageView. You can set image to this imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this really nice tutorial. It should not leave any of your questions open.

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest to follow this approach.A table view has many rows so the image would be too tiny.Do it only if the image are like banners.

**Solution**

If you still want to upload every image in a different row (so in a cell), you can return a cell with a UIImageWiew inside it:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* path; 
    ...   // assign the path according to the index path, so that it loads
    ...   // a different image for every row and section
    UIImage* image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    UITableViewCell* cell=[UITableViewCell new];
    [cell.imageView setImage: image];
    return cell;
}
```

**Alternative Solution**

If instead you want a big image to be displayed, just monitor the row selection, put a big image well below the table view and change the image well contents when the row selection changes.